# How to disable the clear button that IE11 places into textboxes in React Using Styledcomponents Library?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I would like to tell that showing this "clear field" for input elements is IE11 browser behavior. And workaround is to use the following styles :

```
.rcbInput::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

Now , As I am using styledcomponents library in react, How to write pseudo code for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
const Input = styled.input`
  ::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

Comment: Yes. This Worked .
Thank you very much.